# findAllByEntityFieldName() sometimes returns incorrect data with JPA repository

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA Repository.

**My Entity is**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Employee implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "department", nullable = false)
  private String department;

  @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
  private Integer status;
}
```

**Below is my JPA Repository**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

     @Query("select e from Employee e where e.department = ?1 and e.status = ?2 ")
        Page<Employee> findAllByDepartmentAndStatus(Pageable pageable,String department,Integer status);
    
    @Modifying
        @Query("UPDATE Employee SET status = ?1 WHERE id = ?2")
        void updateStatus(Integer status,Long id);
}
```

after updating the status I am calling `findAllByEmpartmentAndStatus` again sometimes it gives updated rows and sometimes return old data and when we refresh the front end page then return the updated rows with correct row size.I tried everything related to cache but did not work. How we can ensure it always return updated result.

Comment: between updateStatus invocation and findAllByDepartmentAndStatus invocation try adding `entityManager.flush(); entityManager.clear();`

Comment: I belive you do not need `@Query(...` in your `findAllByDepartmentAndStatus`.

Comment: @pirho  this is an example .I am using some kind of operator like IN so I have to write the customized query.

Comment: @tremendous7 It is not working .I am calling these two methods in same service but in different methods and on my front end one page update the status and then on redirection findAll query executed.